# R read.xlsx2 : java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: r, xlsx

I got dozens of xlsx files I download from a data provider website. I need to read them with R. To do so I use:

```
data <- read.xlsx2(paste(Filename,".xlsx",sep=""),sheetIndex = 1 ,colIndex = (1:38),startRow = 2,check.names=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,as.data.frame = TRUE,header=FALSE)
```

As you understand my file contains data that begins row 2, on 38 columns.

The problem is, when I run the code above, I get the following error:

> Error in .jcall(Rintf, "[S", "readColStrings", .jcast(sheet, "org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet"),  : 
>     java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

The strange thing, and probably where the problem comes from, is that if I open my file in Excel, and save it as a new file, under the same format (.xlsx), then the code works. And the new .xlsx file is about 2 times heavier than the original one.

Comment: Have you tried using `read_excel()` from readxl package?

Comment: readxl is unable to install even if I install the whole tidyverse package